# NHibernate connection problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am using sql server 2005

but having error message on 
        _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

What is wrong and how can I correct it?

---

My Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property>
<!--<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>-->
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost\SQLServer2005;database=NHibernate101;Integrated Security=True;</property>
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
<mapping assembly="Infrastructure"></mapping>
```

and my in my web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=localhost\SQLServer2005;database=NHibernate101;" providerName="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

---

Error message is:

> NHibernate.HibernateException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.
>     Source=NHibernate
>     StackTrace:
>          at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
>          at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings)
>          at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings)
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
>          at Core.Domain.Repositories.NHibernateHelper.get_SessionFactory() in C:\Documents and Settings\nHibernate101\NHibernate101 Final\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\NHibernateHelper.cs:line 22
>          at Core.Domain.Repositories.NHibernateHelper.OpenSession() in C:\Documents and Settings\nHibernate101\NHibernate101 Final\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\NHibernateHelper.cs:line 30
>          at Core.Domain.Repositories.PostRepository.Core.IRepository.GetAll() in C:\Documents and Settings\nHibernate101\NHibernate101 Final\NHibernate101\Core\Domain\Repositories\PostRepository.cs:line 59
>          at NHibernate101.Controllers.PostsController.Index() in C:\Documents and Settings\nHibernate101\NHibernate101 Final\NHibernate101\NHibernate101\Controllers\PostsController.cs:line 22
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>     InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
>          Message=Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider' to type 'NHibernate.Driver.IDriver'.
>          Source=NHibernate
>          StackTrace:
>               at NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings)
>          InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving that error because in your Hibernate.cfg.xml you're telling NHibernate to use the NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider class for connection.driver_class property. The connection.driver_class property is expecting an IDriver interface while the NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider is not.

Comment: What should be the driver name?

Comment: NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is incorrect. Use this one:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property> 
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property> 
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2000Dialect</property> 
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost\SQLServer2005;database=NHibernate101;Integrated Security=True;</property> 
<property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property> 
<mapping assembly="Infrastructure"></mapping>
```

Comment: Sorry this does not help either

Comment: I`m having the error message:  [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider' to type 'NHibernate.Driver.IDriver'.]
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) +194

Comment: It's because you mixed the Connection Provider and the Connection Driver Class in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the fact that you've specified the SQL2000 dialect rather than the 2005 one? I've never had that happen so I'm not sure if it would raise this error.